# Python built in methods

Tags: python, object

Assume I have a simple array like this:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
```

I can append or pop an element simply by doing:

```
A.append(0)
A.pop(0)
```

But if I turn this into a numpy array:

```
A = np.array(A)
A.append(0)
```

We get the following error (I know you can append an element to a numpy array but it requires more work):

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Because if we check their types we see that they belong to different classes (I want to say that they are different objects but I find this terminology confusing):

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

So apparently I cannot use built-in functions (you would say **methods**) for an object that is created by another guy (for example you cannot use a list if you turn it into a NumPy array because it is not a list anymore)

Then my question is, is this really how it is supposed to be? I mean was this really intended when the object-oriented design was created or are these kinds of things fundamental design flaws?

Comment: "(I know you can append an element to a numpy array but it requires more work):" You cannot append an element to a numpy array, numpy arrays cannot change size. You can *create a new, differently sized array* though

Comment: Yes that is what I mean by doing more work @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: " (I want to say that they are different objects but I find this terminology confusing):" They are different objects, moreover, they have *different types* (i.e. classes, a class is a *type*). So, `x = 1; y = 2` are *two different objects* of the *same type*, `x = "hi"; y = 22` are two different objects of *different types*

Comment: "Then my question is, is this really how it is supposed to be? I mean was this really intended when the object-oriented design was created or are these kinds of things fundamental design flaws?" This is *absolutly how it's supposed to be*. This is not a design flaw, the *whole point* of a class is to define a *type*. Types define the *behavior of a class*. For example, I have an object, `x = "33"`, that is a `str` object, of course, if I have *another kind of object*, `y = 22`, I can't use the same methods. This is a pretty fundamental concept of OOP

Comment: So an object of type `str` has a `.format` method, why *would* an object of a different type, `int`, have `.format`?

Comment: If you turn water into an ice cube, you can't pour it any more.  Because liquid and solid are different things.  Same with arrays and lists.  Different things.

Comment: That isn't "more work", that is two completely different things. This is really a crucial difference to understand

Comment: That is correct but it also comes with some limitations (which are sometimes not useful)

Comment: What limitations? What you are talking about sounds *always useful*.  Again, why should `int` have a `.format` method just because `str` does? So *every object should have every method ever defined in any class?* That doesn't make any sense

Comment: As an aside, `A = [1, 2, 3]` is not an array, it is a *list*.

Comment: "(for example you cannot use a list if you turn it into a NumPy array because it is not a list anymore)" Well, you didn't *turn it into a list*. You created a completely different object, a `numpy.ndarray` object. The list still exists independently of the new object. This is btw, @Samwise why I don't like the "turn water into an ice cube" analogy, because you aren't mutating an object into a different type of object, you are creating a completely new object

Comment: In this int vs str case, it is very nice to have OOP. But the difference in appending an element is not quite the same. It might be quite different in OOP terminology but in reality all I want is just append an integer to a list which only contains integers

Comment: Then you should use a list not a numpy array.

Comment: @goku you **can** append an integer to a list. What is it that you can't do that you want to do, exactly?

Comment: If you just want to deal with lists of integers, why use numpy arrays?

Comment: There is a very important reason that `numpy.ndarray` objects *don't define `.append` and `.pop`*. This isn't a *flaw*, it is a carefully considered design choice. So no, it is exactly lie the `int` vs `str` case

Comment: This is just an example not an actual problem I am having. One may want to use both list and ndarray methods for a given problem.

Comment: And what is that reason? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @goku because `list` objects are designed to have certain performance characteristics, i.e. they are implemented to *change size* (in particular, from the end of the list) **efficiently**. For example, the naive algorithm for a list, `for x in something: mylist.append(x)` is *linear time* on the size of `something`. For arrays, doing the equivalent thing is *quadratic time*, because they aren't designed to grow efficiently, they are designed to be efficient in other ways which require having a constant size. That is the whole point of having the two different types

Comment: This is that case with any two given types that you might use for a given problem. E.g., I could use either a `set` or a `list`, depending on *what behavior I want and what I need to work efficiently*. I would use a set because you can check if `item in myset` *very efficiently* ragardless of the size of the set, on the other hand, I would use a `list` if I want to maintain order and efficiently retrieve an element from the list at a given position, `mylist[33]` (and even though I can check if an `item in mylist`, it is inefficient).

Comment: So, `.append` and `pop` don't make sense as methods for `numpy.ndarray` because `append` and `pop` change the *size of the list*. But *you cannot change the size of a numpy.ndarray*, (that is a core *feature*). There is nothing *stopping* you from defining those methods, but they would be misleading because they would fundamentally be doing different things

Comment: Can't I just inherit from another class that does the same things to different objects than the one I have? (maybe in the case of inheritance they are not different objects)

Comment: Inheritance is part of *creating a new type*. Potentially you *can* create hybrid types with multiple inheritance, but this isn't always possible. Try `class Hybrid(list, numpy.ndarray): ...` and see what happens though... A key concept you need to understant, *classes don't do things to objects*. Classes *define what objects can do*. Inheritance allows you to say "this new class does everything that this base class does", but you can't always do that if you use two base classes with conflicting behavior

Comment: Just another quick question, you said that *You created a completely different object, a numpy.ndarray object. The list still exists independently of the new object*. I think that is very cool but what is the reason for that? Is this because it somehow cannot change the list and overwrite it? Or creating another object is more efficient for some reason? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: And what happens to the old object when the new one is created? You said it still exists but what is the need for that? Seems like memory waste @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: These are just the semantics of the language. That is what *constructors do*, they *create new objects*. In this case, since you re-assigned the new object to the same variable, and that variable was the only other reference to the old object, it is now slotted for garbage collection (and in CPython, will be reclaimed immediately)

Answer (score 3):

The main point of having classes is to define abstractions - that is to define a thing and the operations it provides to its clients (that is, the interface it offers to its clients). Different classes serve different needs and therefore have different interfaces.

Comment: *Precisely*! A "type" is an abstraction, and the way we create a "type" in class-based OOP languages is by defining a class